# Why I get the Html.Hidden error with System.Data.Linq.Binary?

Tags: hidden-field

I want to post the hidden openid data to an action, in the Razor i'm using the following code:

```
@Html.Hidden("OpenID", Request.QueryString["openid"]);
```

And then i'm getting this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'System.Data.Linq.Binary' is defined in an     assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Linq,     Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Source Error:


Line 11: 
Line 12: <form method="post" action="Register">
Line 13:     @Html.Hidden("OpenID", Request["openid"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <compilation debug="true">
  <assemblies>
   <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```